# Customized message for required="true"

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF 1.0. I have a text field with `required="true"`. How can I override the default validation error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a `Messages.properties` file in the `com.example` package with the following content:

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED = Please fill out this field.
```

*(the key is specific to validator behind `required="true"`)*

Then declare the message properties file in `faces-config.xml` as `message-bundle`:

```
<application>
    <message-bundle>com.example.Messages</message-bundle>
</application>
```

*(without file extension!)*

For more message keys, check the JSF specification.

Comment: hi, BalusC thanks for your reply.I am new to JSf. Could you please specify,where can i add messages.properties file and which format it should be. thank you

Comment: I have tried as you have advised. working fine. but how can i display Error Message separately for each field. how to pass message value to each field. Thank you

Comment: This is not possible with JSF 1.0 without creating a custom validator or upgrading to JSF 1.2. The custom validator can replace `required="true"`. Or when upgrading to JSF 1.2 (which should technically be no problem as all JSF 1.x projects are backwards/forwards compatible), then you can use new `requiredMessage` attribute of input component.

Comment: To define your own error messages, create a new properties file, add the adequate error message, for example:

javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED=Hey, you forgot to fill the input {0}!
(note that {0} will be replaced by the ID of the field)

Comment: I tried to define like the same above, but {0} is not being replaced by ID of the field.

Comment: Apparently it's not supported in JSF 1.0. It's definitely supported in JSF 1.2, I can tell that from experience. Not entirely sure about JSF 1.1, for that you'd need to read the specification first. After all, that's just one more reason to upgrade the old beast :) JSF 1.0 is *so* full of bugs and shortcomings. Frankly, I'm surprised to see an apparently live running JSF 1.0 application these days.

Comment: In my messages.prop file i defined like javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED= Please enter a value {0}. Its printing the same on output.

Comment: okay, Thank you BalusC i got it. we are handling a large project in jsf 1.0 so, it will be difficult to migrate to 1.2 or above version.

Comment: I'm not sure how that's difficult. As said, JSF 1.0 is forwards compatible with 1.1/1.2. As to code you actually don't need to change anything. Perhaps you only need to remove several local workarounds to JSF 1.0 bugs (selectonemenu fail is a known one). But this would only end up in less code. Only the migration from JSF 1.x to 2.x requires major code changes.